# My Azure DevOps pipeline job is not working, I have the maximum number of requests reached but I am new

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I am new to Azure and I would like to set up a app service along with a pipeline on devops for continious integration so I decided to try it out with the free plan.

I am trying to set up a pipeline on Azure DevOps with a repository from GitHub and I haven't changed anything in the azure-pipelines.yml so I can test it out if it works. When I run the pipeline and check the default jobs, they are in queue all the time and when I view the messages in the console it says the following:
*This agent request is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism type 'Microsoft-Hosted Private'. Current position in queue: 1*

I have tried Googling around but haven't found anything useful yet except that you have to send an email to a specific address (azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com). Now I have done this, but haven't received any answer yet. Is this the correct solution or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you haven't got agents to build. You can install your own self-hosted agent or use Azure pipelines agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem today, then I noticed this notification banner: "Pipelines in your region may be impacted by a live site incident, resulting in possible pipeline delays."

Comment: Hi @Juweyr. Send the email to specific address is the correct method. Please refer to the answer and check the info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The root cause of the stuck issue is that the pipeline microsoft-hosted agent for public and private projects in the new organization has been restricted in the latest update.

For more detailed info, you could refer to these two docs: [Private Project Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/), [Public Project Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/).

In [Release 183](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-183-update#change-in-process-for-obtaining-free-pipelines-grant-in-public-projects), the reasons for adding restrictions are as follows:

> Over the past few months, the situation has gotten substantially worse, with a high percentage of new public projects in Azure DevOps being used for crypto mining and other activities we classify as abusive. In addition to taking an increasing amount of energy from the team, this puts our hosted agent pools under stress and degrades the experience of all our users – both open-source and paid.

**Private Project:**

You could send email to `azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com` in order to get your free tier.

- Your name
- Name of the Azure DevOps organization

**Public Project:**

You could send email to `azpipelines-ossgrant@microsoft.com` in order to get your free tier.

- Your name
- Azure DevOps organization for which you are requesting the free grant
- Links to the repositories that you plan to build
- Brief description of your project

Since you have sent the email, you could wait for the response and get  your free tier.

Comment: Is there any sort of a timeframe for a response from the team? I've emailed them a few days ago and I'm still waiting to hear back

Comment: Hi @Itamaram. As far as I know, there is no accurate response period, you can wait patiently. Or you could send it again

Comment: I had the same and they didn't respond but my pipeline started working after 2 days from sending an email, and on the settings page I can now see 1800 minutes available, instead of 0

Comment: I am facing this issue. I can see 1800 minutes available on my settings/billing page (https://imgur.com/xudfBMB). But on my settings/parallel jobs page it's says 0 https://imgur.com/hu0CIP6